# Convert a string as a MAC Address

Tags: c#, string

Convert a string into mac address as example `0000001` need to change as `00:00:01` In php i can get it by this `$HexVal=rtrim(strtoupper(chunk_split($hexval, 2, ':')),':');` i need exactly same in C#.
I have the first 6 value as 00:01:AB and i got the last six value from a decimal number. If i input 1 then it needs to change as 00:00:01. so then i con-cat to get my full mac as 00:00:AB:00:00:01.

Comment: ["The standard (IEEE 802) format for printing MAC-48 addresses in human-friendly form is **six groups of two hexadecimal digits**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Notational_conventions). Where's this MAC address hiding then?

Answer (score 3):

OK got it,,

```
 var temp = Regex.Replace("000001", ".{2}", "$0:");
 var tempo = temp.Remove(temp.Trim().Length - 1);//or
 var tempo = temp.Trim(':');
```